# How to install antidote on linux

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install [antidote](https://sourceforge.net/projects/antidote/) on Ubuntu and when I was done, it gave me a link ending in `linux.tar.gz`. Then I opened the folder and found a link ending in `linux.bash` and when I clicked on it nothing happened, it froze. Any help?

Comment: There should be installation instructions inside the .tar.gz file. Look for a file called README or INSTALL.

Comment: or it might be called LISEZ-MOI or INSTALLATION or INSTALLER

Comment: That's the thing. when I click on the tar.gzI file I only reach the linux.bash file and just can't open it.

Comment: I guess you'll need to extract the .tar.gz first, then run the extracted script.

Answer (score 3):

You need to go in the Terminal at the location where you extracted the bash script. After that you need to run:

```
sudo bash Antidote_9.5....  # (use tab completion to get the exact name of the file)
```

It will ask you for your password and then you'll be able to proceed with the installation.